# Any library to handle incoming email and parse it?

Tags: php, email

I'm wondering if there is any php class to handle pipe incoming mail and split headers, body, and split the headers into parts too to easily gather subject and stuffs.

Any recommandations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class HTMLParserIterator
{
    var $contents;
    var $pos=0;
    var $endPos=0;
    function HTMLParserIterator( $contents )
    {
        $this->contents=$contents;
        $this->pos=0;
        $this->endPos=strlen($contents);
    }
    function setPos( $pos )
    {
        $this->pos=$pos;
    }
    function getPos()
    {
        return $this->pos;
    }
    function hasMore()
    {
        return $this->pos <$this->endPos;
    }
    function getChar()
    {
        return $this->hasMore()?$this->contents[$this->pos++]:'';
    }
    function peek()
    {
        return $this->hasMore()?$this->contents[$this->pos]:'';
    }
    function skip($num=1 )
    {
        $this->pos=min($this->pos+$num,$this->endPos);
    }
    function getChars($num)
    {
        $out='';
        $len=min($num,$this->endPos-$this->pos);
        $out=substr($this->contents,$this->pos,$len);
        $this->pos+=$len;
        return $out;
    }
    function readUntil( $until,$ignoreCase=true )
    {
        $end=$ignoreCase?stripos ( $this->contents, $until ,$this->pos ):strpos ( $this->contents, $until ,$this->pos );
        if($end===false)
        {
            $end=$this->endPos;
        }
        $out=substr($this->contents,$this->pos,$end-$this->pos);
        $this->pos=$end;
        return $out;
    }
    function skipWhiteSpace()
    {
        $out=0;
        while( $this->hasMore() && isWhiteSpace( $this->contents[$this->pos] ) )
        {
            $out++;
            $this->pos++;
        }
        return $out;
    }
    function match( $str,$ignoreCase=true )
    {
        if( sWith($this->contents,$str,$ignoreCase,$this->pos ) )
        {
            $out=substr($this->contents,$this->pos,strlen($str));
            $this->pos+=strlen($str);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
define("HTMLParserTag_CONTENT",0);
define("HTMLParserTag_OPEN",1);
define("HTMLParserTag_CLOSE",2);
define("HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE",3);
define("HTMLParserTag_COMMENT",4);
define("HTMLParserTag_EXTENDED_COMMENT",5);
define("HTMLParserTag_SCRIPT",6);
define("HTMLParserTag_STYLE",7);
define("HTMLParserTag_TEXTAREA",8);

class HTMLParserSectionTag
{

    var $type;
    var $value;
    var $attrs=Array();
    function HTMLParserSectionTag( &$iterator )
    {
        if( ($value= $iterator->match( '<!--' ))!==false)
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_EXTENDED_COMMENT;
            $this->value=$iterator->readUntil('-->');
            $iterator->skip(3);
        }
        else if( ($value= $iterator->match( '<!' ))!==false)
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_COMMENT;
            $this->value=$iterator->readUntil('>');
            $iterator->skip(1);
        }
        else if( ($value= $iterator->match( '</' ))!==false)
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_CLOSE;
            $ch=$iterator->getChar();
            $buffer='';
            while( $ch!='' && !isWhiteSpace($ch) && $ch!='>' && $ch!='/')
            {
                $this->value.=$ch;
                $ch=$iterator->getChar();
            }
            if( $this->value=='' )
            {
                $this->value='<'.$ch;
                $this->type=HTMLParserTag_CONTENT;
            }
            else if( $ch=='/' && ($value= $iterator->match( '>' ))!==false )
            {
            }
            else if($ch!='>')
            {
                $endOfTag=$this->readAttrs($iterator);
            }
        }
        else if( ($value= $iterator->match( '<' ))!==false)
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_OPEN;
            $ch=$iterator->getChar();
            $buffer='';
            while( $ch!='' && !isWhiteSpace($ch) && $ch!='>' && $ch!='/')
            {
                $this->value.=$ch;
                $ch=$iterator->getChar();
            }
            if( $this->value=='' )
            {
                $this->value='<'.$ch;
                $this->type=HTMLParserTag_CONTENT;
            }
            else if( $ch=='/' && ($value= $iterator->match( '>' ))!==false )
            {
                $this->type=HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE;
            }
            else if($ch!='>')
            {
                $endOfTag=$this->readAttrs($iterator);
                if($endOfTag=='/>')
                {
                    $this->type=HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->value=$iterator->readUntil('<');
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_CONTENT;
        }
        if( $this->type==HTMLParserTag_OPEN && strtolower($this->value)=="script" )
        {
            $this->readScript($iterator);
        }
        else if( $this->type==HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE && strtolower($this->value)=="script" )
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_SCRIPT;
            $this->value='';
        }
        else if( $this->type==HTMLParserTag_OPEN && strtolower($this->value)=="textarea" )
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_TEXTAREA;
            $this->readUntilEndTag($iterator,"textarea");
        }
        else if( $this->type==HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE && strtolower($this->value)=="textarea" )
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_TEXTAREA;
            $this->value='';
        }
        else if( $this->type==HTMLParserTag_OPEN && strtolower($this->value)=="style" )
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_STYLE;
            $this->readUntilEndTag($iterator,"style");
        }
        else if( $this->type==HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE && strtolower($this->value)=="style" )
        {
            $this->type=HTMLParserTag_STYLE;
            $this->value='';
        }
    }
    function readScript(&$iterator)
    {
        $this->type=HTMLParserTag_SCRIPT;
        $this->readUntilEndTag($iterator,"script");
    }
    function readUntilEndTag(&$iterator,$tag)
    {

        $this->value='';
        while ($iterator->hasMore() )
        {
            $this->value.=$iterator->readUntil( '</'.$tag );
            if( $iterator->match("</$tag>") )
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
            $pos=$iterator->getPos();
                $section=new HTMLParserSectionTag($iterator);
                if( $section->type==HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE && strtolower($section->value)==$tag )
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    $iterator->setPos($pos);
                    $this->value.=$iterator->getChar();
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    function getAttribute( $name )
    {
        return array_key_exists($name,$this->attrs)?$this->attrs[$name]:null;
    }
    function readAttrs(&$iterator)
    {
        while( $iterator->hasMore() )
        {
            if( $iterator->match( '>' ) )
            {
                return '>';
            }
            else if( $iterator->match( '/>' ) )
            {
                return '/>';
            }
            $iterator->skipWhiteSpace();
            $name='';
            $value='';
            $ch=$iterator->getChar();
            while( $ch!='' && !isWhiteSpace($ch) && $ch!='>' && $ch!='=' )
            {
                if( $ch=='/' && $iterator->peek()=='>')
                {
                    $ch='/>';
                    $iterator->getChar();
                    break;
                }
                $name.=$ch;
                $ch=$iterator->getChar();
            }
            if( $ch=='>' || $ch=='/>')
            {
                $this->attrs[$name]=false;
                return $ch;
            }
            $whitespace=(isWhiteSpace($ch)?1:0)+$iterator->skipWhiteSpace();
            if( $iterator->peek()=='=' )
            {
                $ch='=';
                $iterator->skip();
                $whitespace=0;
            }
            $whitespace=$whitespace+$iterator->skipWhiteSpace();
            $value=false;
            if( $iterator->peek()=='\'' )
            {
                $iterator->skip();
                $ch=$iterator->getChar();
                while( $ch!='\'' )
                {
                    $value.=$ch;
                    $ch=$iterator->getChar();
                }
            }
            else if( $iterator->peek()=='"' )
            {
                $iterator->skip();
                $ch=$iterator->getChar();
                while( $ch!='"' )
                {
                    $value.=$ch;
                    $ch=$iterator->getChar();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if( $whitespace==0 )
                {
                    $value='';
                    $ch=$iterator->getChar();
                    while( $ch!='' && !isWhiteSpace($ch) && $ch!='>' && $ch!='=' )
                    {
                        if( $ch=='/' && $iterator->peek()=='>')
                        {
                            $ch='/>';
                            $iterator->getChar();
                            break;
                        }
                        $value.=$ch;
                        $ch=$iterator->getChar();
                    }
                    if( $ch=='>' || $ch=='/>')
                    {
                        $this->attrs[$name]=$value;
                        return $ch;
                    }
                }
            }
            if( $name!='' )
            {
                $this->attrs[$name]=$value;
            }


        }
    }
    function isEntirelyWhiteSpace()
    {
        if( count($this->attrs)==0 )
        {
            for( $i=0;$i<strlen($this->value);$i++)
            {
                if( !isWhiteSpace($this->value[$i]) )
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /*
    define("HTMLParserTag_CONTENT",0);
define("HTMLParserTag_OPEN",1);
define("HTMLParserTag_CLOSE",2);
define("HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE",3);
define("HTMLParserTag_COMMENT",4);
define("HTMLParserTag_EXTENDED_COMMENT",5);
define("HTMLParserTag_SCRIPT",6);
define("HTMLParserTag_STYLE",7);
define("HTMLParserTag_TEXTAREA",8);
*/
    function getAttributesText()
    {
        $out='';
        foreach( $this->attrs as $name=>$value )
        {
            $out.=' '.$name;
            if( $value!==false)
            {
                $out.='="'.str_replace('"','&#34;',$value ).'"';
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
    function getContent()
    {
        $out='';
        switch( $this->type)
        {
            case HTMLParserTag_CONTENT:
            {
                $out=$this->value;
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_OPEN:
            case HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE:
            {
                $out='<'.$this->value;
                $attr=$this->getAttributesText();
                if( $attr!='')
                {
                    $out.=$attr.' ';
                }
                $out.=$this->type==HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE?'/>':'>';
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_CLOSE:
            {

                $out='</'.$this->value.">";
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_SCRIPT:
            {
                $out='<script';
                $attr=$this->getAttributesText();
                if( $attr!='')
                {
                    $out.=$attr.' ';
                }
                $out.='>'.$this->value."</script>";
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_TEXTAREA:
            {
                $out='<textarea';
                $attr=$this->getAttributesText();
                if( $attr!='')
                {
                    $out.=$attr.' ';
                }
                $out.='>'.$this->value."</textarea>";
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_STYLE:
            {
                $out='<style';
                $attr=$this->getAttributesText();
                if( $attr!='')
                {
                    $out.=$attr.' ';
                }
                $out.='>'.$this->value."</style>";
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_COMMENT:
            {
                $out.='<!'.$this->value.">";
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_EXTENDED_COMMENT:
            {
                $out.='<!--'.$this->value."-->";
            }
            break;
        }
        return $out;
    }
    function hasTagName( $name )
    {
        $out=false;
        switch( $this->type)
        {
            case HTMLParserTag_OPEN:
            case HTMLParserTag_STANDALONE:
            case HTMLParserTag_CLOSE:
            {
                $out=strtolower($this->value)==strtolower($name);
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_SCRIPT:
            {
                $out=strtolower($name)=='script';
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_TEXTAREA:
            {
                $out=strtolower($name)=='textarea';
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_STYLE:
            {
                $out=strtolower($name)=='style';
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_COMMENT:
            case HTMLParserTag_EXTENDED_COMMENT:
            {
                if( strtolower($name)=='~comment' )
                {
                    $out=true;
                }
                else if( sWith(strtolower($name),'~comment:' ) )
                {
                    $out=$this->value==substr($name,strlen('~comment:'));
                }
            }
            break;
            case HTMLParserTag_CONTENT:
            {
                $out=strtolower($name)=='~content';
            }
            break;
            default:
            {
                $out=false;
            }
            break;
        }
        return $out;
    }
    function removeAttributes( $name )
    {
        $newAttrs=Array();
        $name=strtolower($name);
        foreach( $this->attrs as $attrName=>$attrValue )
        {
            if( strtolower($name)!=strtolower($attrName) )
            {
                $newAttrs[$attrName]=$attrValue;
            }
        }
        $this->attrs=$newAttrs;
    }
    function removeAttributesStartingWith( $name )
    {
        $newAttrs=Array();
        $name=strtolower($name);
        foreach( $this->attrs as $attrName=>$attrValue )
        {
            if( !sWith(strtolower($attrName),strtolower($name)) )
            {
                $newAttrs[$attrName]=$attrValue;
            }
        }
        $this->attrs=$newAttrs;
    }   
    function removeStyle( $name )
    {
        $name=strtolower($name);
        $styleKey='';
        foreach( $this->attrs as $attrName=>$attrValue )
        {
            if( strtolower($attrName)=='style' )
            {
                $styleKey=$attrName;
            }
        }
        if( $styleKey!='' )
        {
            $styleDef=new HTMLParserIteratorStyleDefintion( $this->attrs[$styleKey] );
            $styleDef->removeStyle($name);
            $this->attrs[$styleKey]=$styleDef->getContent();
        }
    }
    function removeStyleStartingWith( $name )
    {
        $name=strtolower($name);
        $styleKey='';
        foreach( $this->attrs as $attrName=>$attrValue )
        {
            if( strtolower($attrName)=='style' )
            {
                $styleKey=$attrName;
            }
        }
        if( $styleKey!='' )
        {
            $styleDef=new HTMLParserIteratorStyleDefintion( $this->attrs[$styleKey] );
            $styleDef->removeStyleStartingWith($name);
            $this->attrs[$styleKey]=$styleDef->getContent();
        }
    }
    function replaceSources( $srcs )
    {

        foreach($this->attrs as $name=>$val )
        {
            if(strtolower($name)=='src' && array_key_exists($val,$srcs ))
            {
                $this->attrs[$name]=$srcs[$val];
            }
        }
    }
    function getSources(&$srcs)
    {
        foreach($this->attrs as $name=>$val )
        {
            if(strtolower($name)=='src' )
            {
                $srcs[$this->attrs[$name]]=true;
            }
        }
    }
}


class HTMLParser
{
    var $sections=Array();
    function HTMLParser( $contents )
    {
        $iterator=new HTMLParserIterator($contents);
        $this->sections=Array();
        while( $iterator->hasMore() )
        {

            $startPos=$iterator->getPos();
            $section=new HTMLParserSectionTag($iterator);
            $this->sections[]=$section;
            if( $startPos==$iterator->getPos() )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    function getContent()
    {
        $out='';
        foreach( $this->sections as $section )
        {
            $out.=$section->getContent();
        }
        return $out;
    }
    function removeTags( $name )
    {
        $newSections=Array();
        foreach( $this->sections as $section )
        {
            if( !$section->hasTagName($name) )
            {
                $newSections[]=$section;
            }
        }
        $this->sections=$newSections;
    }
    function removeAttributes( $name )
    {
        for( $i=0;$i<count($this->sections);$i++)
        {
            $this->sections[$i]->removeAttributes($name);
        }
    }
    function removeAttributesStartingWith( $name )
    {
        for( $i=0;$i<count($this->sections);$i++)
        {
            $this->sections[$i]->removeAttributesStartingWith($name);
        }
    }
    function removeStyle( $name )
    {
        for( $i=0;$i<count($this->sections);$i++)
        {
            $this->sections[$i]->removeStyle($name);
        }
    }
    function removeStyleStartingWith( $name )
    {
        for( $i=0;$i<count($this->sections);$i++)
        {
            $this->sections[$i]->removeStyleStartingWith($name);
        }
    }
    function removeSections( $name )
    {
        $newSections=Array();
        $openTags=0;
        foreach( $this->sections as $section )
        {
            if( !$section->hasTagName($name) )
            {
                if( $openTags==0 )
                {
                    $newSections[]=$section;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if( $section->type==HTMLParserTag_OPEN )
                {
                    $openTags++;
                }
                else if( $section->type==HTMLParserTag_CLOSE && $openTags>0)
                {
                    $openTags--;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->sections=$newSections;
    }
    function replaceSources( $srcs )
    {
        foreach( $this->sections as $id=>$section )
        {
            $this->sections[$id]->replaceSources( $srcs );  
        }
    }
    function moveSources( $basePath,$oldFolder,$newFolder )
    {
        $srcs=$this->getSources();
        $newSrcs=Array();
        foreach($srcs as $src=>$junk )
        {
            if( substr( $src,0,strlen($oldFolder) )==$oldFolder )
            {
                if( !file_exists($basePath.$newFolder ) )
                {
                    mkdir($basePath.$newFolder );
                }
                $newSrc=$newFolder.substr( $src,strlen($oldFolder) );
                rename($basePath.$src,$basePath.$newSrc);
                $newSrcs[$src]=$newSrc;

            }
        }
        $this->replaceSources( $newSrcs );
    }
    function getSources()
    {
        $srcs=Array();
        foreach( $this->sections as $id=>$section )
        {
            $this->sections[$id]->getSources( $srcs) ;  
        }
        return $srcs;
    }
    function compact( )
    {
        $newSections=Array();
        $openTags=0;
        foreach( $this->sections as $section )
        {
            if( !$section->isEntirelyWhiteSpace() )
            {
                $newSections[]=$section;
            }
        }
        $this->sections=$newSections;
    }

    function removeUpto( $name, $inclusive=false)
    {
        $newSections=Array();
        $found=false;
        foreach( $this->sections as $section )
        {
            if( !$inclusive && $section->hasTagName($name) )
            {
                $found=true;
            }
            if( $found)
            {
                $newSections[]=$section;
            }
            if( $inclusive && $section->hasTagName($name) )
            {
                $found=true;
            }
        }
        $this->sections=$newSections;
    }
    function removeAfter( $name, $inclusive=false)
    {
        $newSections=Array();
        $found=false;
        foreach( $this->sections as $section )
        {
            if( $inclusive && $section->hasTagName($name) )
            {
                $found=true;
            }
            if( !$found)
            {
                $newSections[]=$section;
            }
            if( !$inclusive && $section->hasTagName($name) )
            {
                $found=true;
            }
        }
        $this->sections=$newSections;
    }
}


?>
```

**EDIT: This is actually the part you want, the part above parses the HTML emails.**

```
<?php
define('ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_SERVER_DIRECTORY',dirname(__FILE__).'/storedimages');
define('ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_WEB_DIRECTORY','storedimages');
    if( !function_exists('randomString') )
    {
        function randomString( $len,$chrs='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
        {
          $out="";
          for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
          {
            $out=$out.substr($chrs,rand()%strlen($chrs),1);
        }
        return $out;
      }
    }
class EmailDownloader
{
    var $imageTypesAllowed=Array('JPEG'=>'.jpg','GIF'=>'.gif','PNG'=>'.png');
    var $mbox           =   NULL;   /* mailbox resource */
    function EmailDownloader($username,$password,$mailserver='localhost',$servertype='pop',$port='default')
    {
        if($port=='default')
        {
            $imap_port='143';
            $pop_port='110';
        }
        else
        {
            $imap_port=$port;
            $pop_port=$port;
        }
        if($servertype=='pop')
        {
             $strconnect= '{'.$mailserver.':'.$pop_port. '/pop3}INBOX';
        }
        else if($servertype=='imap') 
        {
            $strconnect= $strconnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$imap_port. '}INBOX'; 
        }
        else 
        {
            die("*** error, mailserver type should be either 'pop' or 'imap'\n");
        }
        $this->mbox=imap_open($strconnect,$username,$password);
    }
    function getEmails($deleteMessages=false,$attachmentLocationServer=ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_SERVER_DIRECTORY,$attachmentLocationWeb=ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_WEB_DIRECTORY)
    {
        $headers=imap_headers($this->mbox);
        //print_r($headers);
        $emails=Array();

        for($idx=0,$mid=1;$idx<count($headers);$idx++,$mid++)
        {   
            $tmpFolder='';
            while ($tmpFolder=='' )
            {
                $tmpFolder='/tmp_'.randomString( 5,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789');
                if( file_exists($attachmentLocationServer.$tmpFolder) )
                {
                    $tmpFolder='';
                }
            }
            mkdir($attachmentLocationServer.$tmpFolder );

            $images=Array();
            $mail_header=imap_header($this->mbox,$mid);
            $fromAddress=($mail_header->from[0]->mailbox).'@'.($mail_header->from[0]->host);
            //print_r($mail_header);
            // $message=imap_body($this->mbox,$mid); # yeah, not so simple, some voodoo needed
            $mob=imap_fetchstructure($this->mbox,$mid);
            if(($mob->type)==0)
            {
                // simple text message so, no problemo!
                $message=imap_body($this->mbox,$mid);
            }else
            {
                // oops, multipart message
            //  echo  get_part($this->mbox, $mid, "MULTIPART");
                $contentParts = count($mob->parts);
                $message=get_part($this->mbox, $mid, "TEXT/HTML", $mob);
                foreach( $mob->parts as $nm=>$part )
                {
                    if( $part->type==5  ||$part->type==3 )
                    {
                        $ext='';
                        if( array_key_exists($part->subtype,$this->imageTypesAllowed) )
                        {
                            $ext=$this->imageTypesAllowed[$part->subtype];
                        }
                        if( $ext=='' && $part->subtype=='OCTET-STREAM' && isset($part->dparameters) )
                        {
                            $attFilename='';
                            foreach( $part->dparameters as $dpara )
                            {
                                if( $dpara->attribute=='FILENAME' ) 
                                {
                                    $attFilename=$dpara->value;
                                }
                            }
                            foreach( $this->imageTypesAllowed as $allowedExt )
                            {
                                if( substr($attFilename,-strlen($allowedExt) )== $allowedExt )
                                {
                                    $ext=$allowedExt;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if( $ext!=''  )
                        {
                            $filename='';
                            while(  $filename=='' )
                            {
                                $filename=randomString( 20,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789').$ext;
                                if( file_exists($attachmentLocationServer.$tmpFolder.'/'.$filename ) )
                                {
                                    $filename='';
                                }
                            }
                            if( $file=fopen($attachmentLocationServer.$tmpFolder.'/'.$filename,'w') )
                            {
                                fwrite($file,imap_base64(imap_fetchbody($this->mbox,$mid,$nm+1)));
                                fclose($file);
                                $images[str_replace(array('>','<'),array('','cid:'),$part->id)]=$attachmentLocationWeb.$tmpFolder.'/'.$filename;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            $emails[]=Array('from'=>$fromAddress,'subject'=>$mail_header->Subject,'body'=>$message,'header'=>$mail_header,'images'=>$images,'tmp_folder'=>$tmpFolder);
            if( $deleteMessages )
            {
                imap_delete($this->mbox,$mid);      
            }
        }
        imap_expunge($this->mbox);
        return $emails;
    }

    function close()
    {
        imap_close($this->mbox);
    }
}
?>



<?
   function get_mime_type(&$structure) {
   $primary_mime_type = array("TEXT", "MULTIPART","MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO","IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER");
   if($structure->subtype) {
    return $primary_mime_type[(int) $structure->type] . '/' .$structure->subtype;
   }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
   }
   function get_part($stream, $msg_number, $mime_type, $structure = false,$part_number    = false) {

    if(!$structure) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($stream, $msg_number);
    }
    if($structure) {
        if($mime_type == get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if(!$part_number) {
                $part_number = "1";
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($stream, $msg_number, $part_number);
            if($structure->encoding == 3) {
                return imap_base64($text);
            } else if($structure->encoding == 4) {
                return imap_qprint($text);
            } else {
            return $text;
        }
    }

        if($structure->type == 1) /* multipart */
        {
            $prefix ='';
        while(list($index, $sub_structure) = each($structure->parts)) {
            if($part_number) {
                $prefix = $part_number . '.';
            }
            $data = get_part($stream, $msg_number, $mime_type, $sub_structure,$prefix .    ($index + 1));
            if($data) {
                return $data;
            }
        } // END OF WHILE
        } // END OF MULTIPART
    } // END OF STRUTURE
    return false;
   } // END OF FUNCTION

?>
```

**EDIT #2:  One More Part to complete the entire process**

```
<?php

    define('RECEIVING_EMAIL_SERVER','mail.server.com');
    define('RECEIVING_EMAIL_ACCOUNT','incoming@server.com');
    define('RECEIVING_EMAIL_PASSWORD','myPasswordIsHere');
    define('DELETE_MAIL_MESSAGES_FROM_SERVER',false);
    define('USE_MYSQL_ESCAPE',false);
    define('STORED_FOLDER_BASE',dirname(__FILE__).'/');
    define('STORED_IMAGES_LOCATION','storedimages');
    define('STORED_IMAGES_LOCATION_ABSOLUTE',STORED_FOLDER_BASE.STORED_IMAGES_LOCATION);
    include_once('class.emaildownloader.php');
    include_once('class.htmlparser.php');
    $getEmail=new EmailDownloader(RECEIVING_EMAIL_ACCOUNT,RECEIVING_EMAIL_PASSWORD,RECEIVING_EMAIL_SERVER);
    $emails=$getEmail->getEmails( DELETE_MAIL_MESSAGES_FROM_SERVER,STORED_IMAGES_LOCATION_ABSOLUTE,STORED_IMAGES_LOCATION );
    $getEmail->close();

    if( $emails )
    {   
echo "EMAILS FOUND: ".count($emails)." <br />";
    }

    foreach( $emails as $email )
    {
echo "PARSING EMAIL<br />";
        $parsedDoc=new HTMLParser($email['body']);
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "script" );
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "style" );
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "head" );
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "applet");
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "embed");
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "object");
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "iframe" );
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "select" );
        $parsedDoc->removeSections( "option" );
        $parsedDoc->removeTags("noscript");
        $parsedDoc->removeTags("html");
        $parsedDoc->removeTags("body");
        $parsedDoc->removeTags("~comment");
        $parsedDoc->removeTags( "input" );
        $parsedDoc->removeTags( "link" );
        $parsedDoc->removeTags( "form");
        $parsedDoc->removeAttributes("background");
        $parsedDoc->removeAttributes("bgcolor");
        $parsedDoc->removeAttributesStartingWith("on");
        $parsedDoc->removeStyleStartingWith('background');
        $parsedDoc->compact( );
        if( count($email['images'])>0 ) 
        {
            $parsedDoc->replaceSources( $email['images'] );
        }
        $subject=explode(' ',$email['subject']);
        if( USE_MYSQL_ESCAPE)
        {
            $project_id=mysql_real_escape_string($subject[0]);
            $page_id=mysql_real_escape_string($subject[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $project_id=addSlashes($subject[0]);
            $page_id=addSlashes($subject[1]);
        }

echo "PARSING COMPLETE<br />";
    }   

?>
```

Comment: @David...it absolutely does.  It parses an HTML email (or if not HTML it falls back to txt).  It reads out the sender, header, attachments, and checks subject line to match expected incoming subject.  This is a class from an email-based CMS i wrote about 4 years ago.

Comment: @David...my bad, i posted the parser portion not the email portion.  I just edited it.  Check again (and take back your down vote...)

Comment: Did you just changed your answer or i was really high XD

Comment: @David.  Yes, I had forgotten the important part and have edited it.  See my comment above.  I think you should now have all you need.

Comment: The issue is that the most important thing is missing, which is spliting the email headers.

Comment: @David hrmm...well, i have one more part and you will then have my entire original script...see the edit above...

Comment: @techtheatre Please, what is this "sWith" undefined function meant for?

Comment: @techtheatre also the "isWhiteSpace" undefined function, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Mail:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html

Specifically:
Zend_Mail_Storage

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html

Note: You don't need to use the whole framework. You can just use the classes you need. It's designed that way.

Comment: hmm, i'd prefer something more independent.

Comment: Independant? What do you mean? You don't have to take my word for it. Read from the horses mouth: "Zend Framework is an open source, object oriented web application framework for PHP 5. Zend Framework is often called a 'component library', because it has many loosely coupled components that you can use more or less independently." http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html